# How To Run This Command "check_ping -H 192.168.1.2 -w 100.0,90% -c 200.0,60%" From Java Code?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, ping

hi i am using linux and trying to execute this command in java and willing to get its result in string variable i have use inetaddress to ping host but my need is to run this command.it is use in "nagios" perhaps it would pe its own command i want to execute this commant in this pattren ??

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/macros.html
above link is for help

```
How it would be possible
```

Hopes for your suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this code ,

```
package testapp;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author siva
 */
public class TestApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            String ls_str;

            String cmd="check_ping -H 192.168.1.2 -w 100.0,90% -c 200.0,60%";
            String cmd1="/bin/ls -aFl";
            Process ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            // get its output (your input) stream

            DataInputStream ls_in = new DataInputStream(
                    ls_proc.getInputStream());

            try {
                while ((ls_str = ls_in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(ls_str);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.err.println(e1);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure abt check_ping cmd, but i have tried with "/bin/ls -aFl", It's working fine...